# Harmonic numbers

Tags: harmonic-numbers

Is there a formula for calculating such a sequence of numbers: 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + ... 1/x? 
I know that the sum of the Harmonic series is equal to infinity, but is there a formula for calculating a collection of numbers to a certain number, for example, to 1/49?

Comment: No simple closed formula is known.  there are some good estimates, which you can read about, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=49th+harmonic+number

Comment: $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(H_{n}-\ln n\right)=$ Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma \approx  0.5772156649$